# conceptual problem in circular combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I'm facing a sort of conceptual problem in circular combinatorics.

> Suppose we have 10 digits in a circular fashion.  We need to select
>   say a 5 digit number string from the digits 0 to 9.  And in that 5 digit
>   number string no two consecutive digits (like 1 and 2 or 9 and
>   0) can be separated by 1 space (that one digit in between for example
>   the number 59418,here digits 5 and 4 are separated by 1 space).

How to approach such a problem?

Comment: In circular permutations, always fix one spot

Comment: Are repeats allowed, or are we selecting without replacement ?

Comment: @trueblueanil  without replacement

Comment: You haven't actually stated a problem to solve.

Comment: Do the 5 selected numbers remain in a circle, or are placed in  a row ?

Comment: in a row.......@trueblueanil

Comment: Not finding an easy way without repetitions....

Comment: Good that you've been trying for so long :) @trueblueanil hope to figure it out soon!

Answer (score 1):

This problem is actually easier than the one in which $9$ and $0$ are not treated as consecutive, since it puts all ten digits on an equal footing.

The first digit has $10$ possibilities ($9$ if you don't allow leading zeros). The second digit also has $10$ possibilities. Then the remaining three digits have $8$ possibilities each, for a total of $10^2\cdot8^3=51200$ possibilities.

Comment: You are assuming one is allowed to use digits more than once. Well, there's nothing in the "question" forbidding it, but then again there's nothing in the question actually asking a question.